# Padding lost on browser zoom (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, zooming, padding

I have the following css defined:

```
#content {
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #176184;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #176184;
    border-right: solid 1px #176184;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
}
```

Everything looks great when I am at "normal" zoom level. However as soon as I reload with increased zoom, Chrome drops the padding. Firefox and IE are fine.
I have tried everything I can think of, and spent hours searching to no avail. This is extremely frustrating, so I would hugely appreciate any tips!

Comment: What You mean by zooming. Ctrl+ ?

Comment: @simon I have tried to replicate your issue without success. I am using Chrome 22. I have tried both zooming the page and increasing/decreasing the font sizes and neither results in dropped padding. Can we have a screenshot or perhaps a JSFiddle/CodePen example to look at?

Comment: -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
These lines are wrong, can you correct the above and verify your results,